# Vue Warnings when using vue-test-utils

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined"

Can someone help with this. I am getting a warning and not able to go ahead with test cases.

Comment: You are using a vuex  `$store.getters` somewhere in your component and you need to mock this.

Comment: Thanks  @ThomasKleßen Kleßen